# how to get the total number of unique fucntions in a JS script

Tags: javascript

I am looking at the source of pace.js and it has a pretty long source code of about a thousand lines. You can view the source [here](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/blob/master/pace.js).

I need to debug this code. Is there any tool or method in JavaScript using which one can identify how many unique functions are there in a given plugin? I found one way which is:

- Paste the code in a text editor
- Identify each function individually
- Paste a console.log("i am so and so function").
- Run the script and copy paste the result from the console in a text editor
- Count the number of functions

Is there a easier way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just get a count of the word "function" using search feature of whatever text editor you're using?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan , good idea ! , but thats just not explicit enough for my non-programming boss .

Comment: Sounds like you need generate some documentation for this code. Would something like JSDoc work?

Comment: putting `console.log`s inside functions (or incrementing a global counter) will give you an idea of how many functions are being *executed*, but not how many *unique* functions there are...

Comment: @AlexMcMillan , i tried your 1st solution , is smart but ineffective , as it counts checks for functions and closures too . i work preferably like to count the , number of functions , directly atttached to the , `prototype` chain . and yeah my technique is not 100% bullet proof , but its slightly better , in the sense , i more so want the functions being executed , rather than the ones that are not , as i will have to debug the functions that are actually running in the background .

Comment: Not "explicit" enough? What does that mean in this context? How much time does your "non-programming boss" want you to spend on this, e.g., what's the ROI?  Technically, this could get non-trivial very quickly, e.g., `Function`s, `eval`s, and so on.

Comment: @vfaller , I don't know what you mean :(

Comment: If you're specifically interesting in functions your code actually uses (which is also problematic if you don't have 100% test coverage) you might want to consider something like [meld](https://github.com/cujojs/meld).

Comment: @Tenali_raman If you simply want a count of unique functions in that block of code, count the number of times the string "function" appears and you have your answer.  If you want to know how many functions are being *executed*, try using a global `count` variable and incrementing like your example.  If you want to get information about how your application is performing, look into [profiling](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/12/javascript-profiling-chrome-developer-tools/)

Comment: @DaveNewton , thanks for the question , basically any method thats faster than the one i am using currently will do ! ... i was expecting an asnwer like `$.uniquefunctionnam.count-the-total-number-of-functions-on-the-prototype-chain()` LOL , but i guess , nothing like that exists !

Comment: You want to know the functions in that code, right? Well a javascript documentation tool like JSDoc or NPM autodoc will parse the code and generate a site that list out all of the functions. Besides I would think that documentation like this would be much more valuable then a function count

Comment: @vfaller i think you come closest to answering my question :) thanks , maybe i'll try that !

Answer (score 1):

This approach first finds all the functions in the window object. Then passes those function references to 'getInnerFunction()' which matches the function against a regular expression to detect any inner functions. Finally the count of functions is returned.

However it will not be able to detect inner functions of native function present in the browser, since they return

```
function FUNCTION NAME {
    [native code]
}
```

this as the to string output.

For other cases this should work. Just call fnCount() and you will receive the number of functions present (subtract 2 from the result to exclude these 2 functions).

** Please correct me if there is any problem with the function matching regular expression.

```
function fnCount(){

var keys = Object.keys(window);
var property;
var count = 0;
for(var i=0;i<keys.length; i++){
    property = window[keys[i]];
    if(typeof(property) === 'function'){
        count += getInnerFunction(property);
    }
}
return count;
}


function getInnerFunction(property){
    var fn = property.toString();
    var fnCount = fn.match(/function.*\(.*\).*{.*/g).length;
    return fnCount; 
}
```

Comment: You can modify the fnCount method and pass in 'Pace' instead of 'window' to get function counts just for that library.

Answer (score -1):

Open notepad++, press CTRL+F, type function, click Find all...

[image]